# PowerShell vs PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell

I have a problem of running my PowerShell script in Task Scheduler. 
I created script in PowerShell ISE and it works fine.

But when I run it by PowerShell it reports some mistakes.

Do you have any ideas why this can happen?

I have tried to create a single line file with

```
powershell_ise.exe -File D:\script.ps1
```

or

```
powershell.exe -File D:\script.ps1
```

But neither of it works.
I have checked policy, but I have it unrestricted.

I have tried to run

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command d:\Script.ps1
```

in PowerShell ISE and it works fine.

When I run it in PowerShell it shows error:

```
The term '▬' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

```
$datetime = Get-Date -f yyyMMdd

$strFileName = "c:\test\BS_" + $datetime + ".txt"

if (Test-Path $strFileName) {
  exit
} else {
  exit
}

...
```

Comment: I wonder what error message `it reports some mistakes` contains. It seems you think those aren't relevant to the problem. Why is that?

Comment: Does the .ps1 file start with a dash `-`?

Comment: No, it is BS_test.ps1

Comment: Please post the script file contents too. Or at least dozen first rows. Copy and paste, do not type. This _might_ be an issue about mixing dash and emdash characters. They do look the same, but shells are picky...

Comment: @vonPryz updated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133059/discussion-between-vonpryz-and-headoverfeet).

Answer (score 0):

The `get-date` cmdlet doesn't have and alias for -format

Please use the below syntax

```
$datetime = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

Comment: You are kind of right, the mistake was in "-" , but it works fine also with -f :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with

```
 $datetime = Get-date -f yyyymmdd
```

whehe I used wrong "-". Thank you all for advices